# How to retrieve all occurrences of a specific key from any level in a JSON String?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let's say I have a `JSON` string like the following:

```
{
    "Id": " 1,
    "Title": "AllLocations",
    "Locations":
    [
        {
            "Title": "LocationA",
            "Latitude": 100,
            "Longitude": 100"
        },
        {
            "Title": "LocationB",
            "Latitude": 100,
            "Longitude": 100"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to easily pull out all occurrences of `Title`, so my result would be the following:

`AllLocations, LocationA, LocationB`

Note how the `Title` tag could appear *at any level* in the hierachy. Is this possible without writing the parsing code myself? A solution using `JSON.Net` would be ideal.

Edit: Apologies if this is a duplicate question. I couldn't find any other question regarding finding values at any level in a `JSON` hierachy.

Comment: For retrieving values that can be in "Any level" I would go with regex'es to be honest. It's will be pretty easy regex.

Comment: *all* levels or *both* levels? (I dont see how you can go deeper than `Locations` with this example)

Comment: @Jamiec *Any* level - even if I have 10 nested elements.

Answer (score 1):

With `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);`

you can check the type of the dynamic in a loop going deeper, if it's also string you are in the "deepest" level of your json and you no longer have to search further

This will also work if your JSON changes over time and is now 100 levels deep for example.

Comment: @Liam I quote OP: A solution using JSON.Net would be ideal.

Comment: "A solution using JSON.Net would be ideal." So that's exactly what he wants.

Comment: Apologies for not adding the correct tags.

Comment: @Teifi just by your score and clear question, does my answer help you, is it detailed enough?

Comment: @Thomas TBH, I'd say no, that's why I haven't given you +1. It needs more detail.

Comment: @Liam I value your input as well but OP's the one who needs help actually